# Kendo MVC Grid Action name missing on first destroy button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid buitl using the MVC extensions like this:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<FooDetailViewModel>()
          .Name("fooGrid")
          .Editable(editable => editable.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are you sure you want to delete this item?"))
          .Sortable()
          .Pageable()
          .DataSource(datasource => datasource
              .Ajax()
              .Read(read => read.Action("GetFooSummaries", "Foo", new { categoryId = @Model.CategoryId }))
              .Model(model => model.Id(x => x.FooId))
              .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Foo"))
          .Columns(col =>
          {
              col.Bound(x => x.FooId).Hidden();
              col.Bound(x => x.FooNumber);
              col.Template(@<text></text>)
                  .ClientTemplate("<a class='blue-tableRowIcon glyphicon glyphicon-edit' href='" + Url.Action("Details", new { id = "#= Id #" }) + "'></a>" + "<div class='k-button-icontext k-grid-delete red-tableRowIcon glyphicon glyphicon-remove' ></div>"
                  )
                  .FooterTemplate("<a class='green-tableRowIcon glyphicon glyphicon-plus' href='" + Url.Action("Details", new { id = Guid.Empty }) + "'></a>")
                  .Title("Action")
                  .Width(94);
          }))
```

My problem is that the delete action on the controller doesn't get called for the *first* delete button I click, but it will on clicks to subsequent rows. For instance, if the grid is showing two rows of data, and I click the delete button for *either one of them* (it doesn't matter which one), I will get a confirmation dialog as expected. If I click "OK", the dialog closes, and a call goes out to the controller, but that call seems to be missing its action name, so the call goes to "http://Site/Area/Foo" and not "http://Site/Area/Foo/Delete" as expected. The row then disappears from the client grid, although the delete action on the controller was never called.

If I then click the delete button on the *other* row and dismiss the dialog, a call goes out to the controller, but this time the action name is filled in, so it wires up properly to the back-end, and I delete the row from the database.

Refreshing the page resurrects the first "deleted" row, since it was never really deleted.

As I said, it doesn't seem to matter which row I click first, or even how many rows there are. Whichever row I try to delete first will not make a correct call to the controller, but any subsequent deletes will. If it were always the first row or something, I'd think it was an off-by-one error somewhere in my code, but the fact that it's always just whichever row you click first indicates a state problem somewhere.

I have replaced the call to destroy.Action with a call to destroy.Url(Url.Action... to no avail, it does the exact same thing.

Has anyone ever seen this? Did you ever work out what the problem was?

Comment: does it work if you use the built it Destroy command button?  `col.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Width(90);`

Comment: Not really sure. There is more than one button in our "Action" column, so that's not really an option. There are other grids in the same application doing this the same way as the view in question, and they are not having the same problem.

Comment: you can use `{ command.Custom(); command.Custom() }` to create as many buttons as you need. But template column works too.. i'd try to duplicate the default destroy button as much as possible though.. i believe it uses an anchor

Comment: I see the same exact behavior. The first "Delete" click pretends to work, but never calls the server. The second "Delete" click does what it's supposed to. At this point, I would normally suspect that something else in the JavaScript of this page is gumming up the works, but there is very minimal JS on this page at all that isn't shared with other pages that are working properly. Kinda stumped.